# Python Overflow Warning in Scalar Add

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, math, integer-arithmetic

I want to perfom a simple operation: b+g+r b,g,r variables are integrers and have value below 256. I get Overflow Warning and wrong results. The problem is that the operation is simple(result not above 765) and I shouldn't get Overflow Warnings

Here is my code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

imgname = 'r_hh_classic.png'

img = cv.imread(imgname)

h,w,_ = img.shape

for y in range(h):
    for x in range(w):
        b,g,r = img[y,x]
        print(b,g,r,b+g+r) #print var b, var g, var r, and b+g+r
        if b+g+r <= 382:
            img[y,x] = 255-img[y,x,0], 255-img[y,x,1], 255-img[y,x,2]

cv.imshow('',img)
```

Python Shell:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/!Saves/_images_/negate 2.py", line 14
    print(b,g,r,b+g+r)
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in scalar add
165 159 191 3

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/!Saves/_images_/negate 2.py", line 15
    if b+g+r <= 382:
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in scalar add
165 159 191 3
165 159 191 3
164 157 191 0
162 156 191 253
161 155 190 250
161 155 190 250
161 154 190 249
160 154 189 247
160 154 189 247
160 152 189 245
159 151 188 242
159 151 188 242
157 151 188 240
157 151 188 240
156 149 186 235
155 148 185 232
154 148 185 231
154 148 185 231
154 146 185 229
152 145 185 226
152 145 185 226
152 145 185 226
152 145 184 225
151 143 183 221
150 143 184 221
150 143 184 221
149 142 182 217
149 142 182 217
149 140 181 214
148 140 181 213
146 139 181 210
146 138 181 209
```

first 3 numbers are b,g,r and 4th is b+g+r but you can see, its extremly wrong

Comment: I think the dtype is uint8, so anything that goes above 255 overflows.

Comment: Numpy operators are not saturated. You can use opencv's `add()` function, see: https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html or you can manually clip and cast to uint8.

Comment: You have np.uint8 operands and you're trying to fit result into np.unit8 as well. A computation involving unsigned operands can never overflow, because a result that cannot be represented by the resulting unsigned integer type is reduced modulo the number that is one greater than the largest value that can be represented by the resulting type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to fit the result in `unit8`
when using dtype `uint8` anything more than 255 overflows.
To avoid overflow use `cv2.add()`
(see [docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html))

*Written as **answer** from coments*

Answered by: @Barmar , @stateMachine , @Severin Pappadeux (see coments)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "needed to close as it already solved". What do you mean?

Comment: @BlueRobin Its solved, I need to close it, I mean Its already answered and if somebody has a similar question they can read the answer directly

Comment: You don't close questions that have an answer. That's not how StackOverflow works. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions#:~:text=When%20a%20question%20reaches%203,reopen%20a%20given%20question%20once.)

Comment: I dont know how to explain right. What I mean is, if someone has the same question they can scroll down to answers, and get their answer directly reading **one** answer, not from reading comments which might have the same information, and, so other people dont waste their time on answering this(if they dont read the comments)